# efficient string search in tcl against list of rules

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to validate if a string matches a list of rules.
For example, which of these list items matches against which of the match rules:

```
set ListToCheck [list abc_123 def_123 ghi_456 abc_345 xyz_987]

set RulesToCheck [list *_123 abc_*]
```

I will eventually have a long list of many dozens of rules to check a long list of strings, and constantly growing.  I only want the first match.

The method I came up with seems to be a little brute force.  I was thinking that there should be a more elegant method

```
set match 0
set matchedrule {}
set matchdict {}
foreach value $ListToCheck {
    foreach rule $RulesToCheck {
        if {[string match $rule $value] == 1} {
            set match 1
            set matchedrule $rule
            break
        }
    }
    <take some action on the $value and $rule matched here>
    ...
}
```

Is this the best method?  I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rules are truly described by glob patterns, there's not a huge amount you can do to optimise detecting which one matches. Well, not unless you get all matching-theoretic and do clever rewriting and all, but that's hard.

You *can* do some things to make a slightly faster matcher. *WARNING!* The following includes code generation.

```
# Build a lambda that uses [switch -glob]
set ruleset {}
foreach rule $RulesToCheck {
    lappend ruleset $rule [list return [list 1 $rule]]
}
set matcher [list value "switch -glob -- \$value [list $ruleset];return {0 {}}"]

# Now we can use the lambda term as much as we want
foreach value $ListToCheck {
    lassign [apply $matcher $value] match matchedrule
    # take some action on the $value and $rule matched here
    # ...
    # I tested with:
    #    if {$match} {puts "$value was matched by $matchedrule"}
}
```

I've not timed this code, but for a reasonable number of rules and items to check, it should do better as it will generate somewhat better bytecode (at a cost of needing to go by an `apply` to do each match, which is about as expensive as calling a procedure).

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to convert the collection of glob patterns into a single RE.

```
# Note that this is Tcl 8.6 syntax - both [lmap] and [string cat] are used
# Rewriting into 8.5 syntax is left as an exercise
set RE [string cat "(" [join [lmap s $RulesToCheck {
    # Assuming you've not got any [...] bits in your glob pattern...
    string cat "^" [string map {* .* ? . \\ {\\}} $s] "$"
}] ")|("] ")"]

foreach value $ListToCheck {
    set matchinfo [regexp -inline -indices -- $RE $value]
    if {[llength $matchinfo]} {
        foreach pattern $RulesToCheck idxs [lrange $matchinfo 1 end] {
            if {[lindex $idxs 0] >= 0} {
                puts "matched $pattern against $value"
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure under what circumstances this will be more efficient than my previous answer with building a lambda; the cost of determining which match occurred seems likely to be irritating in itself (though if the match rate is low enough and the patterns complex enough then *maybe*…)